# Group containers in LXC

Tags: linux, lxc

It's possible to group lxc containers in some kind of hierarchical folder structure?

I means set a group_containers folder in /var/lib/lxc in such a way you could have

/var/lib/lxc/container_1
/var/lib/lxc/container_2
/var/lib/lxc/group_containers/container_A
/var/lib/lxc/group_containers/container_B

inside of each /var/lib/lxc/group_containers/container_A will has the expected container fs for instance:

/var/lib/lxc/group_containers/container_A/config
/var/lib/lxc/group_containers/container_A/rotfs
/var/lib/lxc/group_containers/container_A/snaps